# Routing Breaks on Azure after Changing to .ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, angular-ui-router

After changing my file extensions and routes to point to the renamed .ejs files my app breaks on Azure but works fine locally.

## angularApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('theApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: '/templates/index.ejs',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('view', {
        url: '/view',
        templateUrl: '/templates/view.ejs',
        controller: 'ViewCtrl'
    })
    .state('quote', {
        url: '/quote',
        templateUrl: '/templates/quote.ejs',
        controller: 'QuoteCtrl'
    })
    ...

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index');
}]);
```

## package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.3.3",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the error I get is such

```
GET http://example.azurewebsites.net/templates/index.ejs 404 (Not Found)
```

But again, it works fine locally. Does Azure maybe only have up to some version of "ejs"?

### Edit

Trying an older version of ejs in my package.json (^1.0.0) did not work either.

Comment: Can you load `http://example.azurewebsites.net/templates/index.ejs` directly in your browser?

Comment: No but I can locally.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your project setup. I think it has to do with how you're getting your project onto azure. I'm not familiar with Azure, but if you can get the live sample online, and/or share a repo with code in it (on GitHub for example) then maybe we can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the file extensions can’t be parsed by Azure, it will response 404 code by default, and the ejs template files can only be parsed by node server.

As node.js applications run on iisnode on Azure Web Apps which is configured by `web.config`.

As a result of my test, I need to configure handler maps in `web.config` to let iisnode to treat all files, then I can visit the file directly on browser, also the application works well.

You can use `FTP` tools or `Kudu console`(`https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) to check whether your project file system is proper. If you don't have a `web.config`, add one.

For an easy testing, I put entrance file `index.html` and templates files in public folder in express application architectural directory:

```
-|public/
    |javasripts/
        -angularApp.js
    |templates/
        -index.ejs
    -index.html
```

And the web.config should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="/bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />

        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="bin\www" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If I paste this .config directly into my web.config I now get errors like `[blocked] The page at http://example.azurewebsites.net/ was not allowed to run insecure content from (bootstrap cdn), (angular cdn), (and angular-ui-router cdn)`. Would this have something to do with the `<security>` tags above?

Comment: I also invoked these files from cdn, but it worked for me. How did you deploy your site? To me, I created an empty web app server, deployed my test project to it via GIT, then added the web.config file.

Comment: I ftp'd in to edit my web.config. Then it started working but blocks the bootstrap and angular cdns. I pushed to GitHub to deploy.

Comment: which cdn you chose? could you please provide the URL for to have a test

Comment: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: What's more strange is that my main index was already a .ejs file. And that wasn't failing on azure. It was only when I started using .ejs files for routing.

Comment: Here is a git repo, I leveraged http://techprd.com/develop-simple-angularjs-app-using-nodejs/ ,and modified some files that can deploy on Azure Web apps. It could be helpful for you

Comment: I don't see a git repo.

Comment: To be completely honest, if you want to run a Node app, going through Azure seems like completely unnecessary extra steps that are messing you up on the way. Just run it on Linux or OS X. You can get a bare-bones Linux server at linode.com. Then you can manage a pure Node app without worrying about all that extra Azure stuff. The internet is built on Unix/Linux, afterall.